# Deploy as Web App programmatically from Apps Script browser Editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I understand with the help of `clasp`, we can deploy a script programmatically (even without logging in to the Apps Script editor); however, I was wondering if there are similar functions that allow for us to invoke those APIs directly from the Apps Script editor.

I found the following resources that help with deploying via HTTP GET and POST requests -

- [projects.versions.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.versions/create): Before a script can be deployed, it needs to have a non-zero version available
- [projects.deployments.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/create): Once we have a new version number, we can invoke this API to deploy a script

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any reference apart from this example snippet that could help to invoke these in a way similar to what/how we do other script services ex: `SpreadsheetApp` or `ScriptApp` or `PropertiesService` etc.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for script.projects.versions.create
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/script/v1/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.script.projects.versions.create({
      "resource": {}
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

I understand the above is JavaScript and not specifically useful for Apps Script but...

> Trying to see if there's an Apps Script (browser editor) version of `gapi.client.script.projects.versions.create`

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't an Apps Script version of these functions; however, found this on my quick Google search - https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/script/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/script/class-use/Script.Projects.Versions.Create.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in service available, but you can call the [Apps Script REST API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) directly using `URLFetchApp`.

To handle authorization you'll have to bind your Apps Script project to a GCP project and enable the Apps Script API (on the GCP project).

Then you can set the required OAuth scopes in your apps script project's manifest file (appscript.json). That will allow you to call `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` and use the resulting value as a bearer token that you pass as an Authentication header when you make your `UrlFetchApp.fetch` calls.